# How do I build Multiple Defenses/Security Systems for the same Heaquarters?

Tags: character-creation, powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm taking a slog through **Mutants and Masterminds 3e** again. This time, I'm working on a character with a county-sized headquarters (Awesome headquarters with Grounds feature). In his backstory, the character had acquired himself several plots of land in Nebraska and managed to earn District status for them through shenanigans and malicious compliance. All the complications from this are fairly straight-forward, but I'm drawing a blank as far as making the Security and Defenses flow with that concept.

See, the Grounds feature states that Defense Systems and Security Systems extend through the area surrounding your Headquarters, and the Defense System feature states that it can be any attack effect with a cost no more than double the HQ rank. Keeping in mind that this headquarters is a populated county with its own problems, I don't want to have people blasted with space lasers for loitering, nor do I want a Mall Cop to smack a hover-tank with a nightstick. So, mostly for fluff reasons, **I want to have a handful of different Defense and Security systems in my headquarters that are tooled to different potential situations; how do I do this?**

Answer (score 3):

While not the most satisfying answer from a mechanical point, the most likely answer is that you simply designate the high-power systems for the main grounds, and lower power ones for the surrounding area, as worked out with your GM. Headquarters are generally not the main thrust of the plot, so the game doesn't really go into great detail on them. There is nothing in the rules stating that all defenses have to be at PL, nor does the game go into detail on just how many systems there are in the headquarters.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to improve my answer for you? I checked out Better Mousetrap, which has some headquarters tips, but it doesn't look like they addressed it either.

Comment: @Areadbhair: Is there anything I can add to my answer for you?

Comment: No thanks; despite the non-answer, there isn’t really an answer to begin with (as you said a while ago), so you’re somewhere around correct @Sean Duggan